# Jest simple async await with timer not working

Tags: timer, async-await, jestjs, settimeout

I'm trying to get a simple async/await test working with a setTimeout but nothing is happening when I run it:

```
const testing = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('result');
        }, 500);
    });
}

jest.useFakeTimers()

it('tests async await', async () => {
    const r = await testing();
    expect(r).toBe('result');

    jest.runAllTimers();
});
```

I'd be fine with using real setTimeout like in Jasmine but it seems in Jest you have to use fake ones. So I did include `jest.useFakeTimers()` and `jest.runAllTimers()` but that didn't solve it.

The test gets stuck and never completes. Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
it('tests async await', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    testing = async () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('result');
        }, 500);
      });
    };
    const asyncResult = testing();
    jest.runAllTimers();
    const r = await asyncResult;
    expect(r).toBe('result');
});
```